# Make scrollTo workings in background

Tags: javascript

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Hi Guys! I use this code to make the page scroll down to bottom automatically but when users minimize the browser it's not working anymore. Been looking around for days but can not get through this. Is there a way I can do that by any chance?

Comment: How do you call this function if the window is minimized? What is the scenario? I tried to do this with `timeout` and it's working for me. See [here](http://output.jsbin.com/cipadam)

Comment: Hi Mosh, thanks for your quick reply and yes it's working when I focus on the browser too, but when I set timeout to 5 seconds, refresh the page and immediately minimize the page, it's not working any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you needed

```
var windowHidden = false;
function checkIfFocusOut()
{
    if(windowHidden != document.hidden && document.hidden == true)
    {
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    windowHidden = document.hidden;
}
setInterval(checkIfFocusOut,0.1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ananthakrishnan it works for me now!

Comment: You are welcome, please up vote my answer and happy coding